# How can get all child element from a parent uising EF core

Tags: entity-framework

Propose, Having one class and class has many students. I want to get all of students in class. But I can't get any students from query. Thank you very much for helping.

I use EF core 6

`_context.class`

result is `[classID:1,name:'basic',students[]]`. I hope that result is `[classID:1,name:'basic',students[{StudentID:1,Name:'John'}]]`

Comment: `I use EF core 6`- There is no verion of `EF Core 6`. It can either be `EF Core` or `EF 6`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two classes (code class) "Class" (does this name allowed?) and "Student". 
And your context have:

```
DbSet<Class> Classes {get; set;}
DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
```

and if in Class you have:

```
public List<Student> Students {get; set;}
```

and in Student:

```
public Class Class {get; set;}
public int ClassId {get; set;}
```

then you have 2 options:

1) Get a class with all students.

```
var targetId = 17; //Id of class that we looking for put here.
var classWithStudents = context.Classes.Include(t => t.Students).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == targetId);
```

2) Only get students of this class

```
var targetId = 17; //Id of class that we looking for put here.
var students = context.Students.Where(t => t.ClassId == targetId).ToList();
```